# Ansi join two tables to one table

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join two tables to one table using ansi joins. I can do this in the where

JOIN IN WHERE:

```
select
   name.name,
   middle.name,
   last.name
from
   name,
   middle,
   last
where
   name.middleid = middle.id
   and name.lastid = last.id
   and name.name = 'BOB'
```

I am able to figure out how to join the middle to the name table but once i add in the last table, i'm unsuccessful

```
ANSI JOIN: 
    select
       name.name,
       middle.name,
       last.name
    from
       name join middle on name.middleid = middle.id
       **-- How do i join the name table to the last table?**
    where
    name.name = 'BOB'
```

Comment: Nitpicking: the first statement uses "ansi joins" as well. Just an old version (prior to the introduction of the `JOIN` operator into the SQL standard)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ANSI JOIN: 
    select
       name.name,
       middle.name,
       last.name
    from
       name join middle on name.middleid = middle.id
       join last on name.lastid = last.id
       **-- How do i join the name table to the last table?**
    where
    name.name = 'BOB'
```

Answer (score 0):

its there in your question

```
select
   name.name,
   middle.name,
   last.name
from
   name join middle on name.middleid = middle.id
   join last on name.lastid = last.id 
where
name.name = 'BOB'
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you joined 2 tables think of them as just one with inconvinience of prefixing column names with diferent tables (aka namespaces)

So you again in a spot of joining 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI JOIN:

```
   select
       name.name,
       middle.name,
       last.name
    from
       name 
       join middle on name.middleid = middle.id
       join last on name.lastid = last.id      
    where
    name.name = 'BOB'
```